# Deploy Node.js on tomcat

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-fullstack

I have developed an application using Angular, Node/Express and MySQL. I have deployed my Angular application on the tomcat server, which is connected to some 10 PCs. However, I want to deploy my backend i.e, Node.js/Express.js on the same server as well since my app is totally dependent on the backend. How can I do that? I read online that one cannot deploy node.js on tomcat as both are separate servers. Do I have to install Node.js/MySQL separately on the same server? Isn't there any security threat linked to hosting the front-end and the back-end on the same server machine?
I would really appreciate if someone could clear my mind regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that Tomcat and nodejs are separate web server programs, and you cannot run one within the other.  You can run them both on the same machine, but they must use different ports.

You can use a reverse proxy server (nginx) to project the illusion to your end users that your Tomcat and nodejs apps run on the same server and port. Explaining how to do that is far beyond the scope of a SO answer.

You can share a database server (MySql) between the Java applications running on Tomcat and the Javascript.

There is no inherent security risk in hosting your front-end and back-end code on the same origin server. In fact, there are security advantages, because you can set up restrictive CORS rules.